# add image to EP User Control

Tags: image, user-controls

i added an image to my EP user control .but it doesn't appear  .

```
public string Bind_Image(object Status)
```

{
    string status = Status.ToString();

```
if (status == "0")
{
    return "~/_layouts/ep/images/accept.png";
}
else
{
    if (status == "1")
        return "~/_layouts/ep/images/increase.png";
    else return "~/_layouts/ep/images/minus.png";
}
```

}

when i modify the path to native image like info.png .It appears without pb .should i publish it (so how) or what should i do exactly.thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to add your custom images as a resources in dynamics ax 2012 and go to System Administration/Page de secteur/Paramétrage and select publish images under Eterprise Portal